# How can I set ccshared=-fPIC while executing ./configure?

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I am trying to build Python 2.6 for [QGIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_GIS) on [RHEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) 5.
During the making of QGIS I get the following error:

```
Linking CXX shared library libqgispython.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/python2.6/config/libpython2.6.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/config/libpython2.6.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/python/libqgispython.so.1.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/python/CMakeFiles/qgispython.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What I figure out from this error is that I need to build Python 2.6 with some flag, `-fPIC`.
OK, so I found it in the `configure.in` file but it checks several conditions and on the basis of those conditions it assigns `-fPIC` to the `CCSHARED` flag.

What I did was that after all conditions were checked I added the following line to deliberately use `CCSHARED` as `-fPIC`.

```
CCSHARED="-fPIC";
```

But it did not work..

How to specify while configuring that I want to set `CCSHARED` as `-fPIC`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Run configure with `--enable-shared`.  Then `-fPIC` will be included as part of the shared flags.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I tried running `./configure --enable-shared`, this caused many important Python built-in modules to fail to compile (I'm trying to compile Python 2.7.3 for a 64-bit Ubuntu 11.04 system).  Instead of adding `--enable-shared`, I had to edit `Makefile` and add `-fPIC` after `CC=` as per ashishsony's answer below.

Comment: My modules failed to build too, but that's because I had the bad libpython2.7a already installed into /usr/local/lib!  Deleted that and reran `make`, and everything was happy.

Comment: I was installing on scientific linux 6.4 using environment-modules. I had to delete previous installaiton

Comment: for me running `./configure --enable-shared --with-pic` worked

Comment: You need to add CXXFLAGS and CFLAGS (as per @Crc's solution below). 
Otherwise, you get the same error about -fPIC (at least with Python 2.7.13).  Also, `--with-pic` is not recognized.  Here is what worked for me for Python 2.7.13:  `./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC CXXFLAGS=-fPIC --enable-shared`

Answer (score 15):

The following worked for me when I ran into this error:

```
make clean
./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC CXXFLAGS=-fPIC
```

Answer (score 6):

I got it working by adding `-fPIC` after `CC= gcc -pthread`, 
i.e `CC= gcc -pthread -fPIC` in the Makefile.

Comment: On CentOS 6.5, compiling Python-2.7.5 with `./configure --enable-shared` resulted in an error: `'.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`. I had to edit the Makefile and add -fPIC to the variable as described. This fixed it but it bugs me that I had to do this, but compiling on other machines with Mac and Ubuntu never had this issue, I will investigate further if I have the time.

Answer (score 3):

1. Run `./configure --help`, possibly piping to grep PIC, to see if there's an option to enable this
2. Try setting the environment variable before running configure, e.g. CCSHARED="-fPIC" ./configure (as a single command, assuming bash)

If neither of those work, you need to read the configure code and understand the conditions it tests for better.

Answer (score 2):

As noted elsewhere, running configure with --enable-shared should cause -fPIC to be included in the compiler flags.  However, you may still see the "could not read symbols" error if you attempt to do a parallel build using, e.g., 'make -j8'.  I had this same error on RHEL 5.2 and it only went away when I removed the '-j8' from my make invocation...

Comment: Just seconding evadeflow's answer: should use --enable-shared, and if that's not enough, build using only one thread (no -j option).
I found the 2nd part necessary on a Scientific Linux SLF release 5.7 computer when installing Python 2.7.2.

Comment: I find that if you build python first without configuring for `--enable-shared`, attempting to do so subsequently will cause epic fail as the static lib will be in the path, but the makefile is clearly looking for something else

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that `CCFLAGS`? (Haven't been that side of the world for a while.)

Answer (score 0):

rebuilt the openssl with 
./config --prefix=/software/bea/openssl/100c --openssldir=/software/bea/openssl/100c/ssl shared -fPIC

and then also it dint work. it gave /usr/bin/ld: links failed. 
The we modifed the linking part in make file 
previously it was gcc -Wall -shared -o pwutil.so asciihex.o base64.o bitutils.o dict.o gen_rand.o key_schedule.o md5c.o pdg2_ecb.o pwutils.o random_data.o hexutils.o des3crypt.o blowcrypt.o /software/bea/openssl/1.0.0c/lib/libcrypto.a

we changed libcrypto.a to libcrypto.so after rebuilding with shared option and - fPIC

gcc -Wall -shared -o pwutil.so asciihex.o base64.o bitutils.o dict.o gen_rand.o key_schedule.o md5c.o pdg2_ecb.o pwutils.o random_data.o hexutils.o des3crypt.o blowcrypt.o /software/bea/openssl/1.0.0c/lib/libcrypto.so

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The following has an [example](https://github.com/devopscenter/docker-stack/blob/master/python/Dockerfile#L29) of passing fPIC to configure

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with:

```
./configure --enable-shared --enable-pic
```