# gfortran compilation with -fPIC vs -frecursive

Tags: scipy, fortran, gfortran, lapack

I recently followed the instruction on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496547/python-scipy-needs-blas) for compiling BLAS and LAPACK as pre-requisites to a SciPy installation. First I got a gfortran error at some point, which recommended that I re-compile LAPACK with -fPIC. So I did this by replacing the -frecursive with -fPIC in makefile.inc (which, I assume is some file the Makefile reads for different compile options) and the error was gone.

Can someone explain more generally what the difference is in compiling something with -fPIC and -frecursive, and how it helped fix the error in my case.

Thanks!

Comment: On searching further, I found an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364969/relocation-r-x86-64-32-against-rodata-str1-8)

Comment: .. Except -frecursive has nothing to do with -fPIC -- reading the fort ran compiler man page, you most likely need both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Soren already commented: `-fPIC` is totally unrelated to `-frecursive`. PIC influences how machine code can be positioned inside memory. If you want to compile a library code must be compiled to be relocatable. In other words the code must be able to run regardless of where it is loaded in memory. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5311515/923794) deals with this in more detail.

The `-frecursive` indeed should be specified if possible. Older implementations of `gfortran`, e.g. `gfortran` 4.1.2 on RedHat 5 do not support this option. Currently I haven't seen a workaround, so you have to remove it.
The [gfortran documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Code-Gen-Options.html) describes it as

```
Allow indirect recursion by forcing all local arrays to be allocated on the stack
```

In the thread you mentioned, for compilation of the LAPACK library the option `-frecursive` can be removed. Then the library compiles.

If it works without this feature remains to be seen. Haven't tested yet.