# Why is the CMake solution for "R_X86_64_32 can not be used when making a shared object" specific to x86_64?

Tags: gcc, cmake, portability

I just got this error when compiling some plugins for my new toy (on gcc/g++ on Linux):

> relocation R_X86_64_32 can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

I basically understand [why PIC is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364969/relocation-r-x86-64-32-against-rodata-str1-8) but, within the CMake system, the [solution seems to be this](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-May/014350.html):

```
IF (CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL "x86_64")
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES (${PLUGIN_BASE_LIB} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-fPIC")
ENDIF (CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL "x86_64")
```

I don't understand why this solution is conditional.

The [follow-up](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2007-May/014347.html) seems to suggest that -fPIC should be used basically everywhere except 32-bit Linux, which suggests that the above is not portable.

**Should I always use -fPIC? Will there be any adverse effects?**

`${PLUGIN_BASE_LIB}` needs to be *statically* linked to both the main executable, and *statically* the various shared libraries which are the plugins.

Comment: I haven ever noticed any problem with setting -fPIC apart from minimally more work to do for compiler and runtime. Usually not a problem.

Comment: Using -fPIC and -Werror with mingw may result in an error (I would need to check, not on windows right now)

Comment: @languitar `-fPIC` introduces significant performance penalty because compiler is no longer able to inline and clone functions (as it assumes that it has to preserve symbol interposition semantics).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you want to build two versions of code: one for the main executable and one for the library. The first will need to be compiled with `-fPIE` (which is default in modern distros) and the second with `-fPIC`. As you point out this does not depend on target architecture.

You *can* compile only one version with `-fPIC` but then main executable will be suboptimal because `-fPIC` forces compiler to obey symbol interposition rules which significantly limits it's ability to optimize code e.g. inline and clone functions.