# OpenSSL link libcrypto.a in a static way

Tags: linux, makefile, openssl, g++, libcrypto

I have the following makefile and I would add the library "libcrypto.a" in a static way. I need to do this because the target system cannot install the openssl libraries.

```
    # Environment
    MKDIR=mkdir
    CP=cp
    GREP=grep
    NM=x86_64-linux-nm
    CCADMIN=CCadmin
    RANLIB=x86_64-linux-ranlib
    CC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
    CCC=x86_64-linux-gnu-g++
    CXX=x86_64-linux-gnu-g++
    FC=x86_64-linux-gfortran
    AS=x86_64-linux-as

    # Macros
    CND_PLATFORM=GNU-Linux
    CND_DLIB_EXT=so
    CND_CONF=Release_x86_64
    CND_DISTDIR=dist
    CND_BUILDDIR=build

    # Include project Makefile
    include Makefile

    # Object Directory
    OBJECTDIR=${CND_BUILDDIR}/${CND_CONF}/${CND_PLATFORM}

    # Object Files
    OBJECTFILES= \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/7daaf93a/DtaCommand.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/7daaf93a/DtaDev.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/7daaf93a/DtaDevGeneric.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/7daaf93a/DtaDevOpal.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/7daaf93a/DtaDevOpal1.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/7daaf93a/DtaDevOpal2.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/7daaf93a/DtaHashPwd.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/7daaf93a/DtaHexDump.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/7daaf93a/DtaResponse.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/7daaf93a/DtaSession.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/b7b9df0c/blockwise.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/b7b9df0c/chash.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/b7b9df0c/hmac.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/b7b9df0c/pbkdf2.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/b7b9df0c/sha1.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/822bcbe5/DtaDevLinuxNvme.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/822bcbe5/DtaDevLinuxSata.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/822bcbe5/DtaDevOS.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/GetPassPhrase.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/LinuxPBA.o \
        ${OBJECTDIR}/UnlockSEDs.o


    # C Compiler Flags
    CFLAGS=-m64

    # CC Compiler Flags
    CCFLAGS=-m64
    CXXFLAGS=-m64

    # Link Libraries and Options
    LDLIBSOPTIONS=-lcurses -ltinfo

    # Build Targets
    .build-conf: ${BUILD_SUBPROJECTS}
        "${MAKE}"  -f nbproject/Makefile-${CND_CONF}.mk ${CND_DISTDIR}/${CND_CONF}/${CND_PLATFORM}/linuxpba

    ${CND_DISTDIR}/${CND_CONF}/${CND_PLATFORM}/linuxpba: ${OBJECTFILES}
        ${MKDIR} -p ${CND_DISTDIR}/${CND_CONF}/${CND_PLATFORM}
        ${LINK.cc} -o ${CND_DISTDIR}/${CND_CONF}/${CND_PLATFORM}/linuxpba ${OBJECTFILES} ${LDLIBSOPTIONS} -s

    ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/7daaf93a/DtaCommand.o: ../Common/DtaCommand.cpp 
        ${MKDIR} -p ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/7daaf93a
        ${RM} "$@.d"
        $(COMPILE.cc) -O2 -Werror -I../linux -I../Common -I../Common/pbkdf2 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "$@.d" -o ${OBJECTDIR}/_ext/7daaf93a/DtaCommand.o ../Common/DtaCommand.cpp 

#...... SIMILAR FOR THE OTHER ELEMENTS OF "OBJECTDIR ......"
```

I tried to add to my "LDLIBSOPTIONS" several things but I don't find the correct way to do this, for example:

- "**-lcrypto**" it links the library in a dynamic way (not good for my case)
- "**[absolute path]/libcrypto.a**" it returns "libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
  //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line".

  - "**[absolute path]/libcrypto.a -ldl**"libcrypto.a(evp_enc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What do you want to produce? A statically-linked executable? Or a dynamically linked executable which links libcrypto.a statically? Or a shared object?

Comment: I want to procuce a dynamically linked executable which links libcrypto.a statically.

Answer (score 4):

> OpenSSL link lincrypto.a in a static way 
>   ... 
>   "-lcrypto" it links the library in a dynamic way (not good for my case)

Use `-l:libcrypto.a`. It specifies the full name of the library. Below is from the [`LD(1)` man page](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options). See the part about `:filename`.

> `-l namespec` 
>   `--library=namespec`
>
> Add the archive or object file specified by namespec to the list of
>   files to link. This option may be used any number of times. If
>   namespec is of the form :filename, ld will search the library path for
>   a file called filename, otherwise it will search the library path for
>   a file called libnamespec.a.
>
> On systems which support shared libraries, ld may also search for
>   files other than libnamespec.a. Specifically, on ELF and SunOS
>   systems, ld will search a directory for a library called
>   libnamespec.so before searching for one called libnamespec.a. (By
>   convention, a .so extension indicates a shared library.) Note that
>   this behavior does not apply to :filename, which always specifies a
>   file called filename.
>
> The linker will search an archive only once, at the location where it
>   is specified on the command line. If the archive defines a symbol
>   which was undefined in some object which appeared before the archive
>   on the command line, the linker will include the appropriate file(s)
>   from the archive. However, an undefined symbol in an object appearing
>   later on the command line will not cause the linker to search the
>   archive again.
>
> See the `-(` option for a way to force the linker to search archives
>   multiple times.
>
> You may list the same archive multiple times on the command line.
>
> This type of archive searching is standard for Unix linkers. However,
>   if you are using ld on AIX, note that it is different from the
>   behaviour of the AIX linker.

---

> "[absolute path]/libcrypto.a" it returns "libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5' //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line"

For this problem, add `-ldl` ***after*** `libcrypto` and `libssl` in your link command.

---

> "[absolute path]/libcrypto.a -ldl"libcrypto.a(evp_enc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

For this problem, see [What does .rodata and -fPIC mean when compiling OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25464755/608639) and [Compilation fails with “relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19364969/608639).

The short of it is, you need to configure OpenSSL with the `shared` option. If you don't want to build the shared libraries, the add `-fPIC` to `CFLAGS`. Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `libcrypto.a` is not compiled as PIC (or at least as PIE), and your toolchain defaults to creating PIE-enabled executables.  You probably have to link with a command like this:

```
gcc -fno-pie -no-pie … -Wl,-Bstatic -lcrypto -Wl,-Bdynamic -ldl -lpthread
```

Some parts of libcrypto depend on libdl and libpthread, so these libraries are required, too, but you must link them dynamically because they are part of glibc.

Comment: I tried : "-fno-pie -no-pie -lcurses -Wl,-Bstatic -lcrypto -Wl,-Bdynamic -ldl -lpthread" but when I run the generated images on the target machine, it says that it cannot find 
/usr/lib/libncourses
/usr/lib/libstdc++

Comment: Well, it solved your immediate problem. You didn't say what you actually wanted to do. Static linking is *not* a solution for your problem. You need to replicate the target environment and build against that, and not some other system.