# g++ compile error: `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I am using the command:
`g++ --std=c++11 -fPIC -Iincludes parser.cpp lib/main-parser.o lib/lib.a`

To compile a C++ program on Debian 9. But I am getting the below error message:

`/usr/bin/ld: lib/lib.a(csdocument.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I have already seen the thread:
[Compilation fails with "relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364969/compilation-fails-with-relocation-r-x86-64-32-against-rodata-str1-8-can-not)

However, I have tried adding the `-fPIC` argument however it strangely gives the same error message, along with "recompile with -fPIC"

Any ideas would be appreciated. I have tried compiling this on my University's RedHat systems and it works fine there. I'm thinking it could be a missing dependency, but I've been unable to find any answers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you compile main-parser.o ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I wouldn't be able to provide information on that, as it was pre-compiled and we don't receive information on how it was compiled

Comment: If the haven't used `-fPIC` it could explain the error...

Comment: I get the same error message without using `-fPIC`, too

Comment: @Polymer that you get the same error with and without `-fPIC` implies that it is one of the already-compiled objects that has the problematic relocation. You won't be able to link such an object into a shared library.

Comment: It doesn't matter, because shared objects (SO) are supposed to use position independent code only(!) as they should have an ability to dynamically change their location in RAM

Comment: Are you trying to build a shared object? There seems to be nothing shared object related in your command line.

Comment: In fact the problematic object is given in the error message: `lib/lib.a(csdocument.o)`. How is that built? Also as n.m. notes your command line doesn't specify to build a shared object. Is that really the _complete_ command line you are using?

Comment: I really wouldn't be able to tell you how it is compiled as we don't get that information, the sources are already pre-compiled for us. And yes, `g++ --std=c++11 -fPIC -Iincludes -o jparser parser.cpp lib/main-parser.o lib/lib.a` is the entire input. I am currently in the process of trying the same code on a Debian 8 fresh install (never know)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As it seems gcc is trying to produce a position-independent executable ("shared object" is the hint), tell it not to:

```
g++ --std=c++11 -no-pie -Iincludes parser.cpp lib/main-parser.o lib/lib.a
```

It seems that `g++` produces position-independent executables by default on your system. Other systems would require `-pie` to do so. Using `-no-pie` should create a "regular" (position dependent) executable.

(The error is a result of trying to link an object file that was compiled as non-position-independent into an executable that is supposed to be position-independent).

Comment: I confirm that adding `-no-pie` to the linking options works.

Answer (score 10):

```
/usr/bin/ld: lib/lib.a(csdocument.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.rodata' \
can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

This linker error is telling you that the object file `csdocument.o` in the
static library `lib/lib.a` is not Position Independent Code and hence
cannot be linked with your PIE program. So you need to recompile the source
files of `lib/lib.a` with `-fPIC`, then rebuild the static library, then link
it with your PIE program. If you don't have control of the libary sources
then request a PIC build from its supplier.

(Others have questioned why you should need to build a PIE target at all
since it's not a shared library. In Debian 9, GCC produces [PIE executables
by default](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/ppc64el/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#pie-is-now-default), 
whether programs or shared libraries. The same goes for Ubuntu as of 17.04. )

Comment: Hi, I am having this problem and I don't know how to get the PIC build and use it. Could you please help in my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499568/relocation-r-x86-64-32-against-xxx-can-not-be-used-when-making-a-shared-object

Comment: Quoting that Debian doc: "Note that even though the error message says `-fPIC`, it is sufficient to recompile with `-fPIE` (which is the default in the GCC 6 packages that are part of stretch)."

Answer (score 1):

Adding this worked for me.

```
g++ --std=c++11 -no-pie
```

I also added the `-fPIC` to compile flag.