# "relocation R_X86_64_32 against xxx can not be used when making a shared object" error

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

I am using the `<bcm2835.h>` to connect on the GPIO of my Raspberry Pi. First I implemented a program in C and work perfectly. Now I am translating the same program to C++ and I am getting the error below when I try to start the `<bcm2835.h>`. My Eclipse IDE says `/usr/local/lib/libbcm2835.a(bcm2835.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against`.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`only when I use the function`bcm2835_init()`. I am already using -fPIC to generate the shared library.

```
class HCSR04r {
private:
    int trigger;
    int echo;

public:
    HCSR04();
    HCSR04(int trigger, int echo);
    ~HCSR04();
    uint64_t cyclePulse(int trigger, int echo);
    float distanceCentimeters();
};
#endif 

#include <iostream>
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include "sensor/HCSR04.h"

HCSR04::HCSR04() {
    this->echo = RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_13;
    this->trigger = RPI_V2_GPIO_P1_15;
}

HCSR04::HCSR04(int trigger, int echo) {
    this->echo = echo;
    this->trigger = trigger;
}

HCSR04::~HCSR04() {
}

float HCSR04::distanceCentimeters() {
    return (float) cyclePulse(trigger, echo) / 55.5;
}

uint64_t HCSR04::cyclePulse(int trigger, int echo) {
    if (!bcm2835_init()) // THE ERROR IS BECAUSE THIS LINE
        return 1;

    uint64_t width;

    //Close the bcm2835 bridge
    bcm2835_close();

    return width;
}
```

Now the error...

```
Building target: ../../../lib/libCommunicationLib.so
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -shared -o "../../../lib/libCommunicationLib.so"  ./code/utils/Metric.o  ./code/sensor/GPS.o ./code/sensor/HCSR04.o ./code/sensor/ISensor.o  ./code/CommunicationLib.o   -lpthread -lbcm2835 -lgps
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: //usr/local/lib/libbcm2835.a(bcm2835.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
//usr/local/lib/libbcm2835.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../../../lib/libCommunicationLib.so] Error 1
makefile:47: recipe for target '../../../lib/libCommunicationLib.so' failed
```

Comment: The error message is probably refering to all the other object files you are linking with, `./code/utils/Metric.o` etc. Those files need to be compiled with `-fPIC`

Comment: they already are... `g++ -I"/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/ide/CommunicationLib/../../inc" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -pthread -MMD -MP -MF"code/utils/Metric.d" -MT"code/utils/Metric.o" -o "code/utils/Metric.o" "/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/code/utils/Metric.cpp"`

Comment: it must be something related to the `bcm2835_init()`, because as soon as I use it I get the error.

Comment: I guess I also should mention that I creating a shared library using the bcm2835 lib. I hope this does not influence.

Comment: In that case the question becomes, was the bcm2835.lib library compiled with -fPIC (or equivalent)?

Comment: yes. it was... `g++ -I"/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/ide/CommunicationLib/../../inc" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -pthread -MMD -MP -MF"code/sensor/HCSR04.d" -MT"code/sensor/HCSR04.o" -o "code/sensor/HCSR04.o" "/home/felipe/eclipse-workspace/SENSE-hackathon/code/sensor/HCSR04.cpp"`. I read something about request the PIC build. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827433/g-compile-error-rodata-can-not-be-used-when-making-a-shared-object-recomp/46865480#46865480 but I don't know where to find it....

Comment: I didn't find any better solution so I copied the original source and header file to my project on a different package named external-libraries and I am compiling it inside my project.